# What does an AND gate inside a box mean?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, symbol, clock-speed, system-on-chip

I'm looking at this clock diagram, and it has five of these little boxes with symbols that look like AND gates inside them.  But, they only have one input. What do they mean here?

Source [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0455-stm32h7a37b3-and-stm32h7b0-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

[image: clock diagram]

Comment: (I know nothing about this, but I'm throwing this comment out so someone who _does_ know something can correct me and I can learn ...). Each of those boxed-ANDs goes both into "local" logic in the SCGU box and _also_ is a direct output to the SCEU box.  So maybe they're simply there to pump up the output signal to the SCEU as without them the box labeled HPRE(1) would have quite a large fan-out with a bunch of stuff to drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figure 67. *Bus clock enable logic* shows a little more detail.  The `sys_ck` input to the `SCGU` is shown as a 2-input AND gate.  One input is the clock signal, and the other is a control signal.  This serves as a logical clock gate, where the control signal is the gate enable.  Here is the description for this specific clock signal:

```
As shown in the Figure 67, the enabling of the core and bus clock of each domain depends
on several input signals:
• cpu_sleep and cpu_deepsleep signals from the CPU
• srd_sleepdeep signal
• RCC_xxxxENR.PERxEN bits of peripherals located on the CPU domain
```

The clock gate likely is implemented with special timing to prevent clock glitches when the enable changes.  It may even be implemented as a latch, but it is useful to simply think of it as an AND function from a chip user perspective.

Answer (score 4):

The and symbol is a gate for enabling the clock for cpu core or peripherals. On input will be controlled by a register. This looks like an STM32 bus-structure so likely the reset and clock controller registers will allow control.

Here is an example for the rcc_cpu_ck that is enabled when the cpu is in CRUN mode.

[image]

And here is the actual AND gate:

[image]

Comment: The part is a STM32H7A3 line chip